# проблема с сессиями php. НЕ обявляется сессия

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, столкнулся впервые с проблемой с сессиями на php. Проблема в том, что сессия не создается.

`<?php session_start(); ?> <?php $_SESSION['id'] = 1; echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>`

решения в интернете не нашел, а ошибку выдает Undefined variable: _SESSION in. В куках нет сесии

***РЕШЕНИЕ***

Нужно просто сессию записать так  (т.е в начале и конце php кода поставить пробел) и дальше оставить как отдельную строку. Код будет выглядить так:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $_SESSION['id'] = 1; echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
```

Comment: Это все, что есть из кода ? Если нет, скиньте весь php код

Comment: Здраствуйте. Проблема была решена. Нужно было просто сессию записать так <?php session_start; ?> (т.е в начале и конце php кода поставить пробел) и дальше оставить как отдельную строку

Comment: Так у Вас итак вроде пробелы стоят..что до, что после - ошибка лично у меня не возникала(ет).

Comment: я выше написал, что эту строку нужно оставить отдельно.